# Chrome extension not storing cookies after publishing

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies, google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I am using cookies to keep my user logged into my chrome extension after signup.
Which means my default popup is changed after cookies are detected. This works perfectly fine on my local computer.

But after I publish my chrome extension on chrome web store the functionality goes missing. Each time I click on icon, the popup is the user registration page.

Why is the functionality missing when it works perfectly on my local computer.

Is there a way, I can solve this problem? All my users are facing lot of issues.

Comment: I doubt anyone can help without seeing the relevant code.

Comment: I got my problem solved. Sorry for not correctly posting the question.  I will remove it. Thanks for commenting.